# Is there a dtrace equivalent for .Net

Tags: .net, dtrace

Is there a .Net equivalent or analogue for dtrace?

Comment: It'd help if you explained shortly what dtrace is, because some people may be familiar with something like that on .NET while not knowing dtrace at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly in the sense of a system where you can 'script' the way you can with DTrace.

However there is Event Tracing ([Good intro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx)), which combined with Performance monitoring and Powershell ([Powershell and ETW](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2009/09/08/exploring-and-decoding-etw-providers-using-event-log-channels.aspx) ) could provide you with the information you need. It is not specific to .NET but encompasses a given .NET process (use perfmon for the .NET specific items).

Answer (score 1):

Now that ASP.NET can be run on Linux compatible containers, and those linux compatible containers can be run on SmartOS instead, in effect there may be a possibility of running Dtrace to assist with debugging .NET Code or CoreCLR code at least. 
In fact this has now been done: 
https://www.joyent.com/blog/running-and-debugging-coreclr-on-triton

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are [Windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) and also [perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx)

Comment: dTrace is scriptable.  Is this also the case for Windbg and perfmon?